# What is the component similar to a modal in iPadOS with detents?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I've come across a UI component in iPadOS that behaves like a modal with detents, but I'm uncertain about its name or how to properly implement it. It appears to exhibit detent-like behavior, but when attempting to employ a sheet with detents, it doesn't function as expected on iPad.

[image]

[image]

Could someone please assist me in identifying this component within the iPadOS framework? Additionally, I'm curious whether it's specific to UIKit or if it can be utilized in SwiftUI as well. Any clarification or guidance on effectively using this component, especially with detents, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: By "with detents" what do you mean? That the user can drag it around the screen and it snaps to certain preset positions on the screen? (You should edit your question to clarify rather than adding a comment, so others can figure out what you mean without having to follow a long question-and-answer thread.

Comment: You can see these components in the Maps app on the iPad. You can expand the size like a sheet with detail. But it looks different in comparison to a sheet in iOS.

Comment: @DuncanC I think the author refers to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller/3801903-detents?language=objc as said in https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sheets#iOS-iPadOS but I guess a search on "prefersGrabberVisible" might be a good start for searching infos as it's more specific than just "detents" maybe?

Comment: Is there any reason to think it's anything other than an ordinary UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's some native component which resembles a sheet but, you can achieve something really similar really simply with SwiftUI:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isOpen = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let size = proxy.size
                ZStack {
                    Map()
                    
                    CustomMapSheet(size: size)
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func CustomMapSheet(size: CGSize) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            VStack {
                Text("Content Here")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 4)
                    .padding(.top)
                    .clipShape(.rect)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                let predictedY = value.predictedEndTranslation.height
                                
                                if predictedY > 400 {
                                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                                        isOpen = false
                                    }
                                } else if predictedY < 150 {
                                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                                        isOpen = true
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    )
            }
        }
        .background(.thickMaterial, in: .rect(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
        .padding()
        .frame(width: size.width / 2.8, height: isOpen ? size.height : size.height / 8) // <-- This is for the size
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // <-- This is to Position it to the leading side
        .offset(y: isOpen ? 0 : (size.height - size.height / 2) - 40) // To take it to the bottom when closed
    }
    
}
```

And there you have it

[image: Custom Map Sheet]

Of course you can improve it in multiple ways, but I think it's a good starting point.
Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: I think it's a good option. Since it seems that it's not something official from SwiftUI but rather only available for UIKit, I'm going to try this solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped and provided you with a native SwiftUI solution.